# Detect ios Device is hold Perfect Vertically

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, accelerometer, panorama-control

I want to detect the device is **hold vertically** just like when we are taking the `Panorama Picture`.

What should be the condition for `Accelerometer` for X,Y and Z-axis?

Help me to solve this.

Thank you,

Comment: can't you check condition for landscape & portrait mode? Through that you can detect whether device is hold vertically or horizontally

Answer (score 0):

The force of gravity is always applied to the raw accelerometer, so if the force fector is straight down, then the phone is straight.